# Pointwise convergence of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Following question:

Let X,Z be normed spaces, Y a Banach-space. 
Let $S_k,S \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y), T_k,T \in \mathcal{L}(Y,Z)$ and $S_k \rightarrow S, T_k \rightarrow T$ pointwise.

Then $T_k \circ S_k \rightarrow T \circ S$ pointwise.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Here's a hint: use the uniform boundedness principle

Comment: Hey, is this the only way? Because we didn't have the Banach-Steinhaus theorem in our functional analysis lecture yet so I can't use it without proof..

Comment: Given that you think you cannot apply the UBP, can you provide some context? Is this from a book, lecture notes, homework, etc?  If so, can you link to a pdf, and/or let us know what section this is from?

Comment: Hey, my fault, we didn't have  the Banach-Steinhaus theorom but indeed we had the uniform boundedness principle. Using this, the proof ist pretty easy so thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!